# Give owner full access to there profile share

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This script takes the name of the folder and makes it the owner of the folder. But it does not give the owner full access.

```
$folder = "\\profileshare\profiles\"
$users = (Get-Childitem $folder)
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $acl = Get-Acl $folder\$user
    $current_owner = $acl.owner.split("\")
    if ($user.Name.tolower() -ne ([string]$current_owner[1]).tolower()) {
        Write-Host $user " folder needs owner changed, set to "$user " from " $acl.owner
        $acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$user")
        Set-Acl $folder\$user $acl
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder for $user set correctly"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me give the owner full access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the owner to automatically get full access you need to set an ACE on the parent folder (`\\profileshare\profiles`) granting full control to `CREATOR OWNER` on subfolders and files.

```
$folder = '\\profileshare\profiles'
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
  'CREATOR OWNER',
  'FullControl',
  'ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit',
  'InheritOnly',
  'Allow'
)
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl
```

Without this setting on the parent folder you need to manually revoke the permissions of the previous owner and grant access to the new owner.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for an answer? I posted this same code just last Friday for somebody I'm pretty sure, and it would accomplish what you're looking for. This will construct an ACL for a given user to grant them FullControl, and make children files and folder inherit the access as well.

You only have to set the user object, ACE, and add the ACE to the ACL within the loop, everything else can be defined just once before the loop.

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$folder = "\\profileshare\profiles\"
$users = (get-childitem $folder)
Foreach ($user in $users) 
{
    $acl = Get-Acl $folder\$user
    $current_owner = $acl.owner.split("\")
    if($user.Name.tolower() -ne ([string]$current_owner[1]).tolower())
    {              
        write-host $user " folder needs owner changed,  set to "$user " from " $acl.owner
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("IIS_IUSRS")
        $objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType)
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)
        $acl.SetOwner($objUser)
        set-acl $folder\$user $acl
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Folder for $user set correctly"
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want just one user I need for it to be the owner of the folder to have full access.

Comment: Right, which is why you define the user and ACE within the loop. This does exactly what you're looking for.